# NGXS, best way to dispatch start, success or failure actions from the same action?

Tags: angular, typescript, asynchronous, observable, ngxs

I have the following code for fetching all of my posts

```
`    @Action(actions.FetchPosts)
    fetchAll(ctx: StateContext<PostStateModel>){
        return this.postService.fetchPosts().pipe(tap((postsResults) => {
            const state = ctx.getState();
                ctx.patchState({
                ...state,
                posts: [                    
                    ...postsResults                    
                ],                
            })
        }),
        mergeMap(() => {
          console.log("Inside of mergeMap")
          return ctx.dispatch(new actions.FetchPostsSuccess())
        }),      
        catchError(err => 
        {
          console.log("Inside of catchError")
          return ctx.dispatch(new actions.FetchPostsFail(err))
        }
      ))
    }`
```

This works, however, I want to perform another dispatch prior to calling my post service. What is the best way using async programming to make sure I first dispatch the start action which will set the loading property to true, and then ensure that I only call success once the request returns successfully.

Also, following the ngxs docs, I am using mergeMap() which seems to get the job done. I'm curious though, does the postService which returns an array of posts return a single observable or a single observable which then emits multiple higher order observables (inner observables)?

Comment: No need to dispatch another action just to update the loading to true. you use use the existing FetchPost action to update the state.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could start with dispatching the loading action:

```
@Action(actions.FetchPosts)
fetchAll(ctx: StateContext<PostStateModel>){
    return ctx.dispatch(new ChangeLoadingToInProgress()).pipe(
      mergeMap(() => this.postService.fetchPosts()),
      tap((postsResults) => {
        const state = ctx.getState();
            ctx.patchState({
            ...state,
            posts: [                    
                ...postsResults                    
            ],                
        })
    }),
    mergeMap(() => {
      console.log("Inside of mergeMap")
      return ctx.dispatch(new actions.FetchPostsSuccess())
    }),      
    catchError(err => 
    {
      console.log("Inside of catchError")
      return ctx.dispatch(new actions.FetchPostsFail(err))
    }
  ))
}
```

or I believe you could just change the state right away:

```
@Action(actions.FetchPosts)
fetchAll(ctx: StateContext<PostStateModel>){
    ctx.patchState({ loading: true });
    return this.postService.fetchPosts().pipe(tap((postsResults) => {
        const state = ctx.getState();
            ctx.patchState({
            ...state,
            posts: [                    
                ...postsResults                    
            ],                
        })
    }),
    mergeMap(() => {
      console.log("Inside of mergeMap")
      return ctx.dispatch(new actions.FetchPostsSuccess())
    }),      
    catchError(err => 
    {
      console.log("Inside of catchError")
      return ctx.dispatch(new actions.FetchPostsFail(err))
    }
  ))
}
```

Comment: Both of those answers make perfect sense. I had the second implementation but I wasn’t sure f it was the right thing to do. I thought I had to do what you did there in the first example. Also, shouldn’t I use switchMap for both? Since mergemap maintains the inner subscription where was switchMap will only subscribe to the inner observable until a new one is emitted? Since I am retrieving all posts I think switchMap is what I want for both dispatch. Would you agree?

Comment: @O.MeeKoh you're right about switch map. Definitely should be mergeMap. Regarding which approach to choose - I would actually choose the second one. But its really up to you if you want to have an action to toggle loading state. Imho it would lead to actions explosion. Also what I dont like is the order of actions when you take a look in redux-dev tools - the order is not correct. There is bug for that but currently I dont see any advantage to create a separate action toggling isLoading state.

Comment: @O.MeeKoh and one more thing - I would personally patch the state on success in the `FetchPostsSuccess` handler. The `postResults` should be imho passed to the action as a payload.

Comment: Yeah that is a good point. I will definitely implement both of those tips. Also, do you know why it should “definitely” be mergeMap? Not sure I see the full picture since I’m not so sure about which to use.

Comment: Oh wait looks like here it doesn't really matter. The difference is that switchMap unsubscribes the inner observable on new emit. Since you are always creating a new observable it doesn't matter which one you use. However if you used ngrx (you have ngxs) with `actions$.pipe(ofType(...))` a new action would cancel the old one with switchMap. For example if you have a reload button and you click it more time `mergeMap` will cause multiple requests, `switchMap` will cancel the previous one. Depends on your use.

Comment: Awesome, thats clear now. So generally speaking when you are sending a request to the backend server, and the server responds with a single request (array of items) that single request is treated as a single observable and in that case no inner observables are emitted correct?

Comment: Its more question about if you want concurrently only one request top or not. Imagine that you are supposed to send position of mouse at given time - then you want all your requests to arrive to the server. When one of them is delayed due to the network issues you dont care. But if you had "Refresh products" button and user clicks twice you want to make sure to have just one request and the other canceled so there is no race condition.

Comment: Interesting discussion. For sure it's better to pass the received object to the Success action and patch the state there.
But there is one issue in this approach for NGXS.
Problem is that with such code you will get the wrong order of actions in the redux dev tool.
Here is the GitHub issue:
https://github.com/ngxs/store/issues/139